# Repor Types excluding records

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I wonder about something: when admin create report types

`(including parent and child object ) with Each "A" record must have at least one related "B" record`

option and then create report. The report will include all parent and child objects, then he exclude some child objects - lets call them Type_1.

So my question is: 
What is happend with parents records that has only Type_1 child?
Will they be excluded from report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on my own :)
Reports filters will exclude such parents